# MySQL Workbench draw weak entity

Tags: mysql-workbench

Using MySQL Workbench how can I draw weak entity sets? Does it have anything to do with the tool's non-identifying and identifying relationship?

Answer (score 0):

A entity is called "weak" when its existence depends on the existence of another (i.e., strong) entity.

In MySQL Workbench, click on the relationship between two relations and check "Identifying relation". One example for a weak entity is a dependent of an employee of a company. If you set Model -> Object Notation to either "Classic" or IDEF1X", boxes representing strong entities have sharp corners, while boxes representing weak entities have rounded corners.  Representation of a strong (EMPLOYEE) and weak (DEPENDENT) entity and their relationship, using MySQL Workbench using IDEF1X notation.

[image]